# Class App\Http\Controllers\Panel does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

I'm following the Laracasts series and have run into an issue on the episode `Laravel 5.4 From Scratch: Route Model Binding`.

**Laravel version:**

```
Laravel Framework 5.6.13
```

**The error:**

```
Class App\Http\Controllers\Panel does not exist
```

This shows on both the /panel and /panel/1 pages

**App\Http\Controllers\PanelController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

// Code works if I uncomment below line, and change the show function to "show($panel)"
//use App;

class PanelController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $panels = Panel::all();
        return view('panel/index', compact('panels'));
    }

    public function show(Panel $panel)
    {
        return $panel;
        return view('panel/show', compact('panel'));
    }
}
```

**routes/web.php**

```
// Main panel view
Route::get('/panel', 'PanelController@index');

// Individual panel view
Route::get('/panel/{panel}', 'PanelController@show');
```

**App/Panel.php**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Panel extends Model
{
    public static function activePanels()
    {
        return static::where('status', 1)->get();
    }
}
```

Comment: Add `use App\Panel;` to your `PanelController`

Comment: You need to import your model! Like: `use App\Panel;` It'll find that model and do the things as per your query!

Comment: @kerbholz Thanks. I feel pretty stupid :)

Answer (score 3):

Add this line in panel controller before the class

```
use App\Panel;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `use App\Panel;` to top of class

Or call it by full namespace          `$panels = App\Panel::all();`

Answer (score 0):

You don't included your model to class.

Add `App\Panel` to main include section:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Panel;

class PanelController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $panels = Panel::all();
        return view('panel/index', compact('panels'));
    }

    public function show(Panel $panel)
    {
        return $panel;
        return view('panel/show', compact('panel'));
    }
}
```

or load model in your class method manually:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PanelController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $panels = App\Panel::all();
        return view('panel/index', compact('panels'));
    }

    public function show(Panel $panel)
    {
        return $panel;
        return view('panel/show', compact('panel'));
    }
}
```